# Use strlen with scanf(%ms)

Tags: c, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, strlen

Is it possible to use `strlen()` over a dynamically allocated string?

**FOR EXAMPLE**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char *input=NULL;
  printf ("Enter a sentence: ");
  scanf("%ms", &input);
  //Is this legit?
  printf ("The sentence entered is %u characters long.\n",(unsigned)strlen(input));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will the string be properly terminated? Then yes you can use any string functions. And remember that the format `"%ms"` is a non-standard (and therefore non-portable) extension.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes the string is always properly terminated, i'm not worried about portability anyway

Comment: Just so you know, even if you're not doing portable things for the current program, learning non-portable features leads to bad habits that can come and bite you in the rear once you must use a different compiler or write portably.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the advice! I'm aware of that, but i'm working on a school project not so well organised. They're almost forcing us to write orrible code...

Comment: Note: You can avoid the cast and use `%zu` if you use C99+

Comment: @someprogrammerdude: The `m` modifier is defined by [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html), which is definitely a standard. Or are you saying that Posix functions should never be used? If so, how do you suggest one approaches sockets? :-)

Comment: @rici Defined by *a* standard, not defined by *the* standard: The C standard. And as such, it is unportable and an extension to the C language. :) And the same goes for sockets really, it just happens to be that most other platforms emulate *parts* of the POSIX socket API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `strlen()` on any sequence of `char`s ended by a `'\0'` , the null-character aka `NUL`<sup>*1</sup>, which in fact equals `0`.

It does not matter how the memory has been allocated.

So yes, this also applies to "*dynamically allocated*" memory.

---

<sup>*1: Not be mixed up with `NULL`, which is the null-pointer constant.</sup>

Comment: Is this valid also for strcpy?

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio: Yes, this rules applies to all members of the `str*()`-family of functions.

Comment: Didn't you mean the `NUL`-character?

Comment: @Deduplicator: No. null-character and `NUL`-character are the same.

Comment: @Deduplicator: So to answer your question more accurate: No and yes. ;-)