# does realloc include \0 in reallocated string?

Tags: c, string, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to realloc a string acquired via `scanf("%ms", ...)`, does `realloc` automatically include the termination character `\0` in my reallocated string? What's the behavior of `realloc`in this case?

Will it add `\0` at the end of the reallocated string, or will it leave the `\0` in the same position of the previous string, adding uninitialized memory after `\0`?

**For example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *string = NULL;
    char *p = NULL;
    int length = 0;
    //This should automatically add \0 at the end, if i'm not wrong
    scanf("%ms", &string);
    length = strlen(string);
    p = realloc(string, sizeof(char) * (length + 10));
    if (p != NULL) {
       string = p;
       p = NULL;
    }
    free(string);
    return 0
}
```

**PS**: I used `strlen()` over the string like here: [strlen with scanf("%ms"...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693473/use-strlen-with-scanfms)

Comment: `%ms` is non-standard.  Does your implementation support that?

Comment: @AndrewHenle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685724/difference-between-ms-and-s-scanf It allows you to save a string without knowing the dimension of the input. It's a flag included in POSIX extension

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, it does. I have no problem with the use of %ms

Comment: OK, then how is your program behaving?  `realloc()` is content-agnostic - it doesn't care what the contents of the memory are - it just copies what's in the original to the new memory.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `%ms` is not in C standard but is specified by POSIX standard.

Comment: `malloc` & friends don't have an idea about strings.

Comment: BTW, I recommend you check both the spelling of word *length* and the type of the slash in `\0`. Oh and the type of quotes in `"%ms"`. People will readily assume that you've typoed in your code too if you're lax in these

Comment: Mattia Surricchio, your [referenced link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693473/use-strlen-with-scanfms) casts `strlen()` result to `unsigned`.  Your code used `int length = 0; ...  length = strlen(string);`.  Best to use the same type return by `size_t strlen()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`realloc` doesn't know/care about null bytes or whatever else is stored in the given object. It simply guarantees that the old content is preserved/copied to in the new object it returns (assuming the `realloc` call succeeds). As long you have previously added it, it'll be there after `realloc` too. And in your case, null byte's there (assuming `scanf` succeeded), so it'll be there after `realloc` too.

However, note that if you *shrink* the object with `realloc`, then only the contents up to the specified size will be preserved - in this case, you may not have the null byte after `realloc`.

Answer (score 2):

`realloc()` is not just for characters or integers. It will free the previous memory allocation automatically and then reallocate the requested memory.

> Will it add `\0` at the end of the reallocated string?

It's out of the question.

> Will it leave the `\0` in the same position of the previous string,
>   adding uninitialized memory after `\0`?

`realloc()` doesn't overwrite old contents, not prior memory place. It doesn't touch its content, just moves to and reallocates new memory chunk(s).

Comment: So the answers is "yes" to my second question? I'll end up with the same identical string as before + uninitialized memory after \0?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala by the way, you have changed your profile picture, hamburgers

Comment: @snr not hamburgers, they were Finnish "synonym rolls" ;)

Comment: Detail: "realloc() doesn't overwrite old contents." is not specified true when the allocation shrinks. Even if the same pointer returned, the old contents beyond the new allocation size may or may not be overwritten.  IAC, attempting to access those "beyond" bytes is UB.

Comment: @chux When I'm saying old contents that it is the content which includes old one but in new location. Still isn't there a guarantee of not alteration? And what does _IAC_ mean sir?

Comment: There is not a _guarantee of not alteration_ for the portion of   memory beyond the end of a reduced memory `realloc()`.  IAC --> "In any case".

Comment: @chux so, is usage of  _realloc()_ always risky since the data may corrupt?

Comment: @snr `realloc()` is not risky.  When a re-allocation shrank memory, why should code care if  the data beyond the new smaller size is not   altered?

Comment: @chux actually it is what I try to explain but my explanation might somewhat misleading. Of course, that's right!, sir. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`realloc()` - Changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr.

The content of the memory block is preserved up to the lesser of the new and old sizes, even if the block is moved to a new location. If the new size is larger, the value of the newly allocated portion is **indeterminate**.

You need to allocate the memory for string, using `malloc()` before using `realloc()`.
scanf() will fail to write memory to NULL pointer (string value).

Comment: `char *string = NULL; scanf("%ms", &string);` is not attempting to write to a null pointer as `&string` is never `NULL`.  Perhaps you are thinking of `scanf("%s", string);`?  Suggest researching the library extension `"%ms"`.

Comment: I missed the "m". Sorry, my bad.